# Files downloaded from site - how to address public computers

Tags: website-design, help, download, privacy

Our site allows the user to download PDF files (either stored in our CMS system or created as a Stream from the API) that contains personal financial information

We have a client who has asked if we can stop files being downloaded in case the user is on a public computer

Is there a standard approach, either through code or help text, to advise users to be careful on public computers/devices and to ensure confidential personal information is not left on a public device? Does the responsibility lie on the user with as much guidance as possible from the contextual help?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't want to go for anything that would significantly change expected behavior of downloads, but a well worded confirmation dialog appearing after the user has tried to initiate the download may be appropriate.

Does the site involve any two step authentication login process involving device registration? If yes, you could potentially trigger the two step confirmation of downloads only when the user has logged into a public computer rather than one they've registered as being personal. [image]